# Problems connecting to a freeIPA client host via ssh

Tags: ssh, kerberos, login, single-sign-on, freeipa

I am trying to set up an IPA environment with a CentOS 7.3 server and clients and I am experiencing a behavior that I am not able to understand. I am using IPA version 4.4.0.

I was able to run `ipa-server-install` on the server and `ipa-client-install` on the client without any problems. Then I added a new user `foo` in addition to the already existing user `admin`, which is set up automatically by IPA for administration purposes.

Now to the odd part:

I am able to get a Kerberos ticket with `kinit <user>` for both `admin` and `foo`, also on the client machine. So it seems like the setup has succeeded, I am able to obtain a Kerberos ticket on all hosts and if logged in as root, a `su - foo` also works without problems. Also, when I try to log in over ssh to the IPA **server** machine, say `ssh foo@servermachine`, it works like a charm. However, if I try log in to the IPA **client** machine, i.e. `ssh foo@clientmachine` I get disconnected immediately:

```
! user@machine >ssh foo@clientmachine
Password:
foo@clientmachine's password:
Connection closed by 172.27.0.104
```

Interestingly, ssh asks for the password twice. `ssh -vvv` after the second password attempt yields:

```
foo@clientmachine's password:
debug3: packet_send2: adding 64 (len 57 padlen 7 extra_pad 64)
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
Connection closed by 172.27.0.104
```

The more interesting side is on the client (ssh server), where `journalctl -xeft sshd` shows this message after entering the password for the first time:

```
Jun 29 15:53:00 clientmachine sshd[5464]: pam_sss(sshd:auth): authentication success; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=machine.domain.com user=foo
Jun 29 15:53:00 clientmachine sshd[5464]: pam_krb5[5464]: TGT verified using key for 'host/clientmachine@REALM'
Jun 29 15:53:00 clientmachine sshd[5464]: pam_krb5[5464]: authentication succeeds for 'foo' (foo@REALM)
Jun 29 15:53:01 clientmachine sshd[5464]: pam_sss(sshd:account): Access denied for user foo: 4 (System error)
Jun 29 15:53:01 clientmachine sshd[5461]: error: PAM: User account has expired for foo from machine.domain.com
```

and the second time:

```
Jun 29 15:56:10 clientmachine sshd[5483]: pam_sss(sshd:auth): authentication success; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=machine.domain.com user=foo
Jun 29 15:56:10 clientmachine sshd[5483]: pam_krb5[5483]: TGT verified using key for 'host/clientmachine@REALM'
Jun 29 15:56:10 clientmachine sshd[5483]: pam_krb5[5483]: authentication succeeds for 'foo' (foo@REALM)
Jun 29 15:56:10 clientmachine sshd[5483]: Failed password for foo from 10.128.34.50 port 55327 ssh2
Jun 29 15:56:10 clientmachine sshd[5483]: fatal: Access denied for user foo by PAM account configuration [preauth]
```

I have double-checked that the account is *not* expired and moreover, as stated before, login as user foo via ssh works without problems if I connect to the IPA server machine. The respective `sshd` log:

```
Jun 29 16:00:11 servermachine sshd[29995]: pam_sss(sshd:auth): authentication success; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=machine.domain.com user=foo
Jun 29 16:00:11 servermachine sshd[29992]: Accepted keyboard-interactive/pam for foo from 10.128.34.50 port 34662 ssh2
Jun 29 16:00:11 servermachine sshd[29992]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user foo by (uid=0)
```

Summarizing:

- `kinit foo` on server machine: Works
- `kinit foo` on client machine: Works
- `su - foo` when logged in as root on server machine: Works
- `su - foo` when logged in as root on client machine: Works
- `ssh foo@servermachine`: Works
- `ssh foo@clientmachine`: **Does not work!**, ssh client gets disconnected immediately

I am not able to understand what is going on and I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `pam_krb5` in parallel to `pam_sss`. Why do you have it configured?